existence of a Dirac mass in the conditional laws of a random couple
Let $\pi$ be the joint law of $(X, Y)$ with marginal distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$. We assume that we have:
for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu(A) > 0,
\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y}(A) = 1\}\right) > 0.$
where $\pi_{Y=y}$ is the conditional law of $X$ given $Y=y$.
I am asking if necessarily:
$\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y} \text{ is a Dirac measure}\}\right) > 0$.
This is true if $X$ has atoms: if $x$ satisfies $\mu(\{x\}) > 0$, then by hypothesis: $\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y}(\{x\}) = 1\}\right) > 0$
so $\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y} \text{ is a Dirac measure}\}\right) > 0$.
I am unable to prove this in general or find any counterexample. Thank you very much for your help.

would you mind showing how this applies in case of atoms?

@SBF I have done it!
